# OnDeserialized for JSON causing object to be null

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net, deserialization

I have a route on my WebAPI project that accepts an object as input `ExportPostData`. `ExportPostData` has a property called "contract" of type `Contract` which was successfully being populated when I called the route. I added the `[OnDeserialized]` tag to the `Contract` class and now it always fails deserialization. There are no errors thrown, just `Contract` is null. I have no idea how to debug this since my OnDeserialized method never even gets hit.

**ExportPostData**

```
public class ExportPostData
{
    public Contract contract { get; set; }
    public bool includeSubItems { get; set; }
    public string user { get; set; }
    public string[] projects { get; set; }
}
```

**Contract**

```
public class ZEstimateContract
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string contractName { get; set; }
    public string contractNumber { get; set; }
    public string updatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime updated_at { get; set; }

    [OnDeserialized()]
    internal void Deserialized()
    {
        // THIS NEVER GETS HIT 
        Console.WriteLine("I'm deserialized");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
[OnDeserialized()]
internal void Deserialized()
{
    // THIS NEVER GETS HIT 
    Console.WriteLine("I'm deserialized");
}
```

to this:

```
    [OnDeserialized]
    internal void Deserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
        // THIS GETS HIT NOW
        Console.WriteLine("I'm deserialized");
    }
```

Without the parameter, the method's signature doesn't match what OnDeserialized is looking for. See this article for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute.aspx